# Problem with upgrading 19.04 to 19.10 "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

I did `do-release-upgrade -d` and got this traceback. Earlier I did some experimenting with `upgrade-alternatives` pointing `python` to `python3` and pointing `python3` to `python3.8` but I `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python` and `sudo apt install --reinstall`ed both of them.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,319 kB]                                                                  
Fetched 1,320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                 
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'eoan.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                        
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                 
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                              
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 802, in _prepare_snap_replacement_data
    di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0]
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/eoan", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2084, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1921, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 927, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 97, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 129, in eoanPostInitialUpdate
    self._calculateSnapSizeRequirements()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 459, in _calculateSnapSizeRequirements
    self._prepare_snap_replacement_data()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 808, in _prepare_snap_replacement_data
    (r.version for r in di.get_all("object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 802, in _prepare_snap_replacement_data
    di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0]
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/eoan", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2084, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1921, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 927, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 97, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 129, in eoanPostInitialUpdate
    self._calculateSnapSizeRequirements()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 459, in _calculateSnapSizeRequirements
    self._prepare_snap_replacement_data()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ymy3ktjy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 808, in _prepare_snap_replacement_data
    (r.version for r in di.get_all("object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874250/comments/9 "this seems to typically stem from a pip-installed version of distro-info shadowing the apt version" and you can get rid of the pip-installed version with

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall distro-info 
sudo apt reinstall python3-distro-info
```

Comment: This might be because I piped `pip list` to `pip install -U` to upgrade all my Python dependencies as per this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip . I can see that it installs `distro-info` version 0.0.0.

Comment: I ran into this issue again when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 and I can confirm the above two commands fixed it.

Comment: Same issue and same solution going from 20.10 to 21.04

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. 
I solved it with following steps:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Enter the following instructions:

   ```
   wget https://salsa.debian.org/debian/distro-info/raw/master/python/distro_info.py 
   sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distro_info.py  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distro_info.py.old
   sudo cp distro_info.py /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distro_info.py
   ```
3. Launch the command:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

Comment: This also worked for me when I couldn't upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 with the same error.

Comment: Yes, this did work for me with a minor edit; while these instructions aim to solve a problem for Python3.7 I had the same error for Python3.6.
I copied the distro_info.py file to /usr/local/lib/Python3.6/dist-packages/ instead.

Comment: The same instructions are also valid for the migration to the distribution 19.10 and 20.04: in some cases the problem has recurred on these occasions.