# Python dist-packages UnicodeDecodeError when upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, python, 19.04, do-release-upgrade

I tried to run the `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Unfortunately i get an error traceback pointing to python dist-packages. I replaced the dist_info.py like described in [Problem with upgrading 19.04 to 19.10 "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182208/problem-with-upgrading-19-04-to-19-10-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-d#) without any success. I have no idea how to get the upgrade done and appreciate any help.

P.S. On my laptop the upgrade went seamlessly

Thanks

```bsh
(base) ...:~$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1.554 B]                                                                                    
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1.329 kB]                                                                                             
Fetched 1.331 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                            
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'eoan.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                     
Hit https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                                            
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
No candidate ver:  account-plugin-facebook
No candidate ver:  account-plugin-flickr
No candidate ver:  account-plugin-google
No candidate ver:  appmenu-qt5
No candidate ver:  cgmanager
No candidate ver:  conquest-common
No candidate ver:  cuda-cudart-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-cudart-dev-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-cufft-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-cupti-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-curand-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-cusolver-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-cusparse-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-npp-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nsight-compute-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nsight-systems-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvcc-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvgraph-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvjpeg-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvprof-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvrtc-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-nvtx-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-toolkit-10-1
No candidate ver:  cuda-visual-tools-10-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/eoan", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2082, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1919, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 967, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.tasks = self.cache.installedTasks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 809, in installedTasks
    for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 724: invalid start byte
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/eoan", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2082, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1919, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 967, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.tasks = self.cache.installedTasks
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-85qno1dr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 809, in installedTasks
    for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 724: invalid start byte
```

My pythons:

```bsh
(base) ...:~$ which python
/home/.../anaconda3/bin/python
(base) ...:~$ ls -al /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Apr  1 11:35 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mär  4  2019 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3691008 Okt  7 19:36 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Okt  7 19:36 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mär  4  2019 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     385 Jan 30  2019 /usr/bin/python2-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     389 Jan 30  2019 /usr/bin/python2-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     154 Dez  4  2018 /usr/bin/python2-pbr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     365 Jan 29  2019 /usr/bin/python2-qr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr  1 13:18 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4877888 Okt  7 14:56 /usr/bin/python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Okt  7 14:56 /usr/bin/python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4877888 Okt  7 14:56 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Okt  7 14:56 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Nov 22  2018 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mär 26  2019 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     364 Jan 29  2019 /usr/bin/python3-qr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Mär  4  2019 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config
```

**EDIT**

I was not able to resolve the problem so i upgraded my system manually by changing the /etc/apt/sources.list (every disco to eoan) and do the apt update/upgrade/full-upgrade steps. Beside some lost settings this worked just fine.

Comment: `python` on 19.04 & 19.10 should refer to python 2.7 (`python2` in 20.04 speak). You may have better luck by returning python back to standard before your upgrade.

Comment: Thanks but I got no luck with that.