# Upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 impossible

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

I tried to upgrade my computer from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. I tried first using the graphical manager, but it didn’t work. I then opened a terminal and typed `sudo do-release upgrade` but I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 185, in _get_from_and_to_version
    di.version('%s' % self.controller.fromDist).split()[0]
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/eoan", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2082, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1919, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 925, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 97, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 116, in eoanPostInitialUpdate
    self._get_from_and_to_version()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-r0ftfkno/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 191, in _get_from_and_to_version
    (r.version for r in di.get_all("object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Tue Apr 14 13:31:08 2020) ===
```

To fix this, I ran:

- `sudo dpkg -a --configure`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apr upgrade`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Except `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, these commmands worked when I ran them, but didn’t fix the upgrade problem.

Could someone tell me what must I do to fix this problem?

Comment: "This bug was fixed in the package ubuntu-release-upgrader - 1:19.10.9" https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1833753

Comment: or try this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1848829/comments/12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with upgrading 19.04 to 19.10 "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182208/problem-with-upgrading-19-04-to-19-10-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-d) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137645/python-error-when-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04

Comment: @pLumo I tried https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1848829/comments/12, but it didn’t worked: I still get the same message.

Comment: @pLumo I went to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182208/problem-with-upgrading-19-04-to-19-10-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-d and apparently, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185662/269948) did the trick for me. I’ll confirm it once the upgrade complete.